# What is the finite expansion of $\ln(\sin x)$ to order 3 in the neighborhood of 0?

Tags: real-analysis

I am having hard time calculating the finite expansion of $\ln(\sin x)$. I tried getting the finite expansion of $\sin x$ alone then substituting it in the $\ln$ function but I ended up with having $\ln x$ in the answer.

Comment: Are you aware that there is an essential singularity at $x=0$?

Comment: You cannot avoid that singularity.

Answer (score 4):

We have a nice development of $\ln$ around $1$.
$$\tag1 \ln(1+x)=x-\frac {x^2}2+\frac {x^3}3-\frac {x^4}4\pm\ldots.$$
However $\sin x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$,
$$\sin x =x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\mp\ldots.$$ We cannot plug this into $(1)$, but we know that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$, for which $(1)$ is applicable.
$$ \tag2\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}\mp\ldots$$
Plug $(2)$ into $(1)$, ignoring higher powers (which is justified) to obtain
$$\begin{align}\ln\frac{\sin x}{x}&=\left(-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}\mp\ldots\right)-\frac12\left(-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}\mp\ldots\right)^2\pm\ldots \\
&=-\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{180}\pm\ldots\end{align}$$
so that 
$$ \ln\sin x= \ln x-\frac16x^2+O(x^4)$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking this on the real line, but the situation is no better in the complex plane. You need to think about what you know of the function - have you tried to sketch it?

In the neighbourhood of $0$ the function $\sin x$ changes sign, so the logarithm is undefined for $x\le 0$ and on the positive side the logarithm tends to $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$ so the leading term of any expansion would be $-\infty$.

So what meaningful expansion do you expect to find?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can see the Sine as its exponential representation 
$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

and then compute the $\log$ as

$$\log(\sin(x)) = \log\left(\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}\right) = \log(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}) - \log(2i)$$

and now use Taylor series for exp:

$$\log\left(\left(1 + ix + \frac{(ix)^2}{2} + \frac{(ix)^3}{6}\right) - \left(1 - ix + \frac{(-ix)^2}{2} + \frac{(-ix)^3}{6}\right)\right) - \log(2i)$$

namely

$$\log\left(i\left(2x - \frac{x^3}{3}\right)\right) - \log(2i) = \log\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(2x - \frac{x^3}{6}\right)\right) = \log\left(x - \frac{x^3}{3}\right)$$

And this is exact because what you have inside the parentheses is the correct Sine expansion up to order three. You surely could have done it in the same way by using directly the Sine series. Anyway, $\sin(0) = 0$ so in this point there are problems because function tends to $-\infty$ (for $x\to 0^+$).

From the writings above you can always collect an $x$ and write in the same way:

$$\log(x) + \log\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat ad-hoc, one might say that to the third degre, $\sin x \approx x-\frac16x^3 = x(1-\frac16x^2)$, so
$$ \log(\sin x) \approx \log x + \log(1-\frac16 x^2) $$
And Taylor expanding the second logarithm we get
$$ \log(1-\frac16x^2) \approx -\frac16x^2 - \frac1{72}x^4 + \cdots $$
where the $x^4$ and higher terms can be discarded because we're only interested in the third order. Thus,
$$ \log(\sin x)) \approx \log x - \frac16x^2 $$

---

(This could be made mode rigorous by introducing some $o(x^3)$s and waiting with Taylor expanding the sine until the initial logarithmic term has been handled and $\log(\frac{\sin x}{x})$ is left.)

Answer (score 0):

You can compose asymptotic expansions  *with the same order*. Now, in a neighbourhood of $0$, if $x>0$,
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4),\quad \ln(1-u)=-u+o(u)$$
hence
$$\ln(\sin x)=\ln x+\ln\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}6+o(x^3)\Bigr)=\color{red}{\ln x-\frac{x^2}6+o(x^3)}.$$